# How to include content files in project if resources are specified in nuspec file?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am creating a nuget package definition to include a whole bunch of DLLs. Some of them are needed only at design time, so according to the [Nuspec Reference](http://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#specifying-explicit-assembly-references) I created a `references` section to specify which assemblies should be referenced by the project.

I also specified a list of files to be included. Some of these files being the libraries, one is a PowerShell script that gets executed during package installation and one is simply a content file that should be added to the project lateron.

These are the relevant sections of my nuspec file:

```xml
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <!-- Most of the metadata stuff left out for brevity -->
    <dependencies />
    <references>
      <reference file="MyComponent.dll" />
      <reference file="MyComponent.Data.dll" />
      <reference file="MyComponent.Other.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="MyPackage.install.ps1" target="tools\install.ps1" />
    <file src="MyComponent.ReadMe.txt" target="ReadMe.txt" />
    <file src="C:\Some\Path\MyComponent.*.dll" target="lib\net45" />
    <file src="C:\Some\Path\MyComponent.*.xml" target="lib\net45" />
    <file src="C:\Some\Other\Path\*.dll" target="lib\net45" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Now here is my problem: **The licenses.licx file does not get included in the project when the package is being installed. What must I change to achieve this?**

Adding it to the `references` section does not work, because, well, it is no library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. To include a file into the targeted project the file needs to be placed in a sub-folder named `content` in the package's folder structure:

The correct `files` section of the nuspec file would then look like this:

```xml
<files>
  <!-- other files omitted for brevity  -->
  <file src="MyComponent.ReadMe.txt" target="content\ReadMe.txt" />
</files>
```